# java.lang.classnotfoundexception with ant + Junit

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to get a simple Ant script running, but I'm unable to make it execute tests. I have so many problems that I'm hardly sure where to begin. I'll just start with the small 'simplified' project I created with a couple of really simple test cases. Ultimately I would like to fork="yes" and forkmode="once" but right now I've turned it off while debugging.

My build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Test1111" default="tests" basedir=".">

    <property name="projectName" value="Test1111"/>
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="bin" location="bin"/>
    <property name="dist" location="dist"/>
    <property name="lib" location="lib"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
            <include name="jmockit.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="init">
        <tstamp/>
        <mkdir dir="${bin}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${bin}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>
        </javac>
        <copy todir="${bin}">
            <fileset dir="${src}" excludes="**/*.java"/>            
        </copy>
    </target>   

    <target name="tests" depends="compile" description="Run unit tests">
        <junit printsummary="withOutAndErr" fork="no" forkmode="once" haltonfailure="yes" failureproperty="junit.failure">
            <classpath path="lib/jmockit.jar"/>
            <classpath path="lib/junit.jar"/>
            <classpath path="lib/ant-junit.jar"/>
            <classpath path="lib/hamcrest-core.jar"/>
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
            <batchtest>
                <fileset dir="${src}">
                    <include name="**/*Test*"/>
                    <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
                </fileset> 
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="clean up">
        <delete dir="${bin}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Here's the Ant console output, with -verbose and -debug flags.

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on February 26 2012
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on February 26 2012
Setting ro project property: ant.file -> C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\build.xml
Buildfile: C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\build.xml
Adding reference: ant.projectHelper
Adding reference: ant.parsing.context
Adding reference: ant.targets
parsing buildfile C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\build.xml with URI = file:/C:/Users/abanana/workspace/JMockitSimpleTest/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.project.name -> Test1111
Adding reference: Test1111
Setting ro project property: ant.project.default-target -> tests
Setting ro project property: ant.file.Test1111 -> C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type.Test1111 -> file
Project base dir set to: C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest
 +Target: 
 +Target: init
 +Target: compile
 +Target: tests
 +Target: clean
Adding reference: ant.LocalProperties
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Setting project property: projectName -> Test1111
Setting project property: src -> C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\src
Setting project property: bin -> C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\bin
Setting project property: dist -> C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\dist
Setting project property: lib -> C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\lib
Adding reference: classpath
Setting ro project property: ant.project.invoked-targets -> tests,clean,compile,init
Adding reference: eclipse.ant.targetVector
Build sequence for target(s) `tests' is [init, compile, tests]
Complete build sequence is [init, compile, tests, clean, ]
init:
Setting project property: DSTAMP -> 20130708
Setting project property: TSTAMP -> 1043
Setting project property: TODAY -> July 8 2013
    [mkdir] Skipping C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\bin because it already exists.
compile:
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\src with patternSet{ includes: [] excludes: [] }
    [javac] simpletest\SimpleClass.java omitted as C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\bin\simpletest\SimpleClass.class is up to date.
    [javac] simpletest\SimpleInterface.java omitted as C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\bin\simpletest\SimpleInterface.class is up to date.
    [javac] simpletest\test\SimpleTest.java omitted as C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\bin\simpletest\test\SimpleTest.class is up to date.
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\src with patternSet{ includes: [] excludes: [**/*.java] }
     [copy] No sources found.
     [copy]  omitted as C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\bin is up to date.
     [copy] bin omitted as C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\bin\bin is up to date.
     [copy] simpletest omitted as C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\bin\simpletest is up to date.
     [copy] simpletest\test omitted as C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\bin\simpletest\test is up to date.
tests:
    [junit] Found C:\Users\abanana\workspace\CIMP\lib\junit-4.11.jar
    [junit] Found C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-launcher.jar
    [junit] Found C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant.jar
    [junit] Found C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-junit.jar
    [junit] Found C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-junit4.jar
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\src with patternSet{ includes: [**/*Test*] excludes: [**/AllTests.java] }
    [junit] Using System properties {java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin, java.vm.version=23.21-b01, ant.library.dir=C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, path.separator=;, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, user.script=, user.country=US, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, user.dir=C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest, java.runtime.version=1.7.0_21-b11, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment, java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\endorsed, os.arch=x86, java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\TTHORA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\, line.separator=
    [junit] , java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, user.variant=, os.name=Windows 7, ant.home=C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609, sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252, java.library.path=C:\eclipse;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;;C:\eclipse;;.;C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\332\1\.cp, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=51.0, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Client Compiler, os.version=6.1, user.home=C:\Users\abanana, user.timezone=America/New_York, java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob, file.encoding=UTF-8, java.specification.version=1.7, java.class.path=C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-antlr.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-apache-bcel.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-apache-bsf.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-apache-log4j.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-apache-oro.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-apache-regexp.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-apache-resolver.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-apache-xalan2.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-commons-logging.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-commons-net.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-jai.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-javamail.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-jdepend.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-jmf.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-jsch.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-junit4.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-netrexx.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-swing.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-testutil.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant.jar;C:\Users\abanana\workspace\CIMP\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\abanana\workspace\CIMP\lib\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Users\abanana\workspace\CIMP\lib\tools.jar;C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\60\1\.cp\lib\antdebug.jar;C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\60\1\.cp\lib\remote.jar;C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\61\1\.cp\lib\remoteAnt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\lib\tools.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.100.1.v4236b.jar, user.name=TThorarensen, java.vm.specification.version=1.7, sun.java.command=org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner -debug -verbose -Dorg.eclipse.ant.core.ANT_PROCESS_ID=1373294617517 -Declipse.connect.port=56425 -Declipse.pdebuild.home=/C:/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.2.v20121114-140810/./ -Declipse.pdebuild.scripts=/C:/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.2.v20121114-140810/scripts/ -Declipse.pdebuild.templates=/C:/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.2.v20121114-140810/templates/ -Dant.home=C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609 -logger org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.logger.RemoteAntBuildLogger -inputhandler org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.inputhandler.ProxyInputHandler -buildfile C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\build.xml tests clean compile init, java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre, sun.arch.data.model=32, user.language=en, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit, java.vm.info=mixed mode, sharing, java.version=1.7.0_21, java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext, sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\classes, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, file.separator=\, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.desktop=windows, sun.cpu.isalist=pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86}
    [junit] Implicitly adding C:\Users\abanana\workspace\CIMP\lib\junit-4.11.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-junit4.jar to CLASSPATH
    [junit] Using CLASSPATH C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\lib\jmockit.jar;C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\lib\junit.jar;C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\lib\hamcrest-core.jar;C:\Users\abanana\workspace\CIMP\lib\junit-4.11.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-junit4.jar
Class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.PlainJUnitResultFormatter loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class simpletest.test.SimpleTest
    [junit] Running simpletest.test.SimpleTest
    [junit] Testsuite: simpletest.test.SimpleTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] simpletest.test.SimpleTest
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: simpletest.test.SimpleTest
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    [junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    [junit]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    [junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    [junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    [junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\abanana\workspace\JMockitSimpleTest\build.xml:34: Test simpletest.test.SimpleTest failed
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.actOnTestResult(JUnitTask.java:1954)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:854)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1899)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)

Total time: 351 milliseconds
```

I'm using Eclipse on Windows and run the build script from within Eclipse. I feel like I've tried everything but I hope someone here recognizes something that may be off.

**Edit:** SimpleTest.java:

```
package simpletest.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import mockit.*;

import simpletest.SimpleClass;
import simpletest.SimpleInterface;

public class SimpleTest {

    static final class SimpleImpl implements SimpleInterface {
        public int doSomething() {
            System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeInterface() {
        SimpleInterface si = new MockUp<SimpleInterface>() {
            @Mock
            int doSomething()
            {
                // intentionally left blank;
                return 1;
            }

        }.getMockInstance();

        assertEquals(1, si.doSomething());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInterfaceAgain() {
        final SimpleInterface thing = new SimpleImpl();
        /*
        new NonStrictExpectations(SimpleImpl.class) {{
            thing.doSomething(); result = 1;
        }};
        */
        final SimpleClass simple = new SimpleClass();

        simple.setSimpleInt(1);

        assertEquals(simple.getSimpleInt(), thing.doSomething());
    }

}
```

**EDIT II:** `<pathelement path="${bin}"/>` was  missing from the classpath and seems to have resolved the issue (although still not able to fork). Good 'nuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference to a class in your simpletest.test.SimpleTest where Ant can not find it. You have to make sure Ant knows where to look for that class.

```
[junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: simpletest.test.SimpleTest
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

Comment: how do I do that? I thought the batchtest tag would be taking care of it? Can you link me to the relevant docs?

Comment: Please edit your question and add SimpleTest source so I can better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${src}">
        <include name="**/*Test*"/>
        <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
     </fileset> 
</batchtest>
```

To

```
<batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${bin}">
        <include name="**/*Test*"/>
        <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
     </fileset> 
</batchtest>
```

It looks like the ant script can't find your test classes, but the `<batchtest>` task should be able to take `.class` files as a resource.

Comment: That was a great idea which I should have thought of before, although unfortunately I get the same output... let me get back to you, I have to check something out though.

Comment: I now get this: http://mysticpaste.com/view/rJIp54J4Nm?2

Most notably, it does say 

`[junit] Implicitly adding C:\Users\abanana\workspace\ProjectX\lib\junit-4.11.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\lib\ant-junit4.jar to CLASSPATH`

I'm not sure how to turn that off, but this could possibly be a problem, no?

Comment: I think I have it figured out.  You have a static inner class that's probably compiled to something like `simpletest.test.SimpleTest$SimpleImpl.class` in your `bin` directory.  I'm guessing the ant script is trying to run that as a unit test class.  Can you try commenting that out along with any references to it and see if the unit test runs correctly then?  If that's the case, then you just need to modify the ant task to skip inner classes.

Comment: I just tried this, unfortunately that isn't it :( You can see it here (although the syntax highlighting is a bit wonky) http://mysticpaste.com/view/yH4N8YEdj6?5

Comment: Did you run an `ant clean` before you ran that?  It might have picked up the `.class` file in the `bin` directory if it wasn't deleted.

Comment: I actually did make a mistake with the order. I changed the order round so that it runs clean, init, compile, tests and this is the output (after fixing classpath in compile, as well):

[http://mysticpaste.com/view/A9v7HNqH6I?12](http://mysticpaste.com/view/A9v7HNqH6I?12)

Answer (score 0):

You should only run `*Test` classes; your additional wildcard at the end is going to wreak havoc.

In addition, you need to put `bin` on the junit classpath; without it, there aren't any class definitions actually *available* to junit.